# Why does my image for my Stage icon come out as an oval?

Tags: javafx-8

Attached is the image I use for my JavaFX stage icon. It comes out as an oval on both the Stage and the application Icon on the taskbar (e.g. Windows).

Does anyone have an idea why?

[image]

Comment: Because your image's width differs from it's height.

Comment: Thanks fabian, and sorry for missing this. That's odd, though you may be right. I'm quite sure that the image was saved under the same width and height dimensions.